# Raster becomes invisible after changing CRS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, netcdf

I am having trouble displaying this netcdf file in QGIS. The file holds u and v components of wind data from NCEP Climate Forecast System.

When I load the data, it displays over the ocean near Africa and has an invalid projection. When I set the CRS to 4326 (`properties-->source-->set CRS`) and Zoom to Layer, the map moves to California (the correct location of the data) but the raster is invisible. I've tried saving the raster layer with 4326 CRS and I've tried reprojecting and assigning a projection. Unsure how to fix this.

Link to data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PZsYLNp4wirX2BQjZ_CwsyNE3OpT8G1x/view?usp=sharing

NCEP info: https://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds094.2/index.html#!description

Comment: Can you try it with `'Warp(reproject)'` from the Processing Toolbox, do you get the same error?

Comment: @Taras, yes same error after Warping to 4326.

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but the extent for the raster layer seems odd. 
Extent for raster file that doesn't show up:   

233.8977272396995772,32.0953943179203876 :  
 246.9886405581519568,42.9301450802729647  

Extent for different raster from NCEP that shows up:  
-126.2500000000000000,31.7500000000000000 :  
 -112.7500000000000000,43.2500000000000000  

The long values are almost exactly 360 off from each other.

Comment: setting the CRS doesn't change the data's position it just confuses QGis by making it think the data is somewhere else.